# private wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to create a category/post that will not show in the post listing but the post will be available via direct link.

Basically, I want the post/page/category to be viewable only by those I sent the link. I don't want to make it available in the post listing. I don't want it password protected also.

If possible that that the specific post is not visible to search engine, that's much preferable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You could always:

1) [Register a Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). In this example, we would name it something like "Private".

2) Set up your archive template (archive-private.php) to either redirect to a different page (maybe homepage, or 404), or style it in some way to look like a different page (maybe homepage, or 404) so the posts can't be listed

3) Set up your single post template (single-private.php) to format and display your private post however you like.

You wouldn't have to worry about your existing queries targeting any private posts, no passwords would be required, and the single-posts will be viewable and the archive not viewable. The nice thing too is that if you set 'public' to false in your arguments, the posts won't show up in any searches within the site.

As far as hiding it from search engines themselves, you need to set that within your [Robots.txt File](http://codex.wordpress.org/Search_Engine_Optimization_for_WordPress#Robots.txt_Optimization).

Bear in mind, this won't PREVENT Search Engines from displaying what's in your Disallow list. It is up to the Search Engine itself as to whether or not it will honor your disallow list.

Comment: looks like a solution but I can't really grasp it at my level. Will try to explore further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. If there is a way, you'd have to extensively modify your theme's PHP settings.